# Where would I add a Coursera course to Stack Overflow Careers?

Tags: support, jobs

I've recently done a [Coursera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coursera) course that I wish to reflect on my [Careers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Careers) profile, but I'm not sure where I would put this since I don't believe it precisely counts as a certification, but more of an addition to my education section.

Also, when you complete the course you get a certificate of completion, and there isn't any place where I can upload this PDF file or link to it for it to be shown on my profile.

Comment: If you believe it belongs to the education section, add it there. As for the PDF - you can always send it if asked for it (and make a point that you welcome such requests).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I added one in the Education section under the title **Independent Study**, *Stanford* in place of a degree/institution.

> Completed the Introduction to Artificial Intelligence online course offered by Sebastian Thrun and Peter Norvig (now on [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs271)).

I'd consider the PDF certificate of completion to be roughly equivalent to a transcript, so I'd just provide that if requested.

Comment: mm... that https site gave me a big warning!

Comment: @Braiam Thanks.  I updated the link to point to the course's new home on Udacity.

Comment: It would be great if there specific section where online certificates & courses could be linked.

Comment: @JonnyBoats That might be a good idea for a separate feature request. It's been two years since this was asked. I now have a bunch of certificates from Coursera on my LinkedIn profile, but always forget to add them on Careers because its not set up as seamlessly.

Answer (score 10):

The problem with adding these to the education section is they are not in the same league as a degree, and they clutter the section, especially if you have many. CVs need to be short and easy to parse. A Coursera course, while substantial, is still more like a single class at university. It shouldn't look equal to a degree in the profile.

A second problem is that people tend to place their education chronologically, with the most advanced (and therefore most recent) degree at the top. Online courses typically happen after formal education in time, but putting them first gives them undue precedence. I'd much rather an employer saw my highest degree than some Coursera course.

For these reasons, I've added my Coursera courses to the 'Certifications' section, even though they are not certifications in the traditional sense.

I believe there should be a separate section for such courses, in the same vein as online articles, and open source repositories.

Comment: I fully agree with you, a separate section about MOOC is a must nowadays. It should also be noted that some courses do not provide a certificate so certificate section is not always useful.

Answer (score 3):

Anyone still looking for an answer:
As of 2021, there's a separate section of certification in StackOverflow. So you may add certifications (professional, single, specialization, etc.) from MOOC providers like Coursera or edx in your stackoverflow profile